# Is there any way i can get the address of a Buffer in Deno?

Tags: typescript, memory, buffer, deno

The equivalent of **Buffer.from** of node in Deno is something like:

```
import {Buffer} from "https://deno.land/std/io/buffer.ts";
const buf=new Buffer(new Uint8Array(10).fill(41));
```

In node i can get the reference address of a Buffer with **buf.address()** from "ffi-napi" addon with something like this:

```
var FFI = require('ffi-napi');
var buf= Buffer.from([0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41])
console.log(buf.address())
```

Deno have already builtin support for ffi to load an external library with **Deno.dlopen** but not a way to acquire a pointer to a buffer

Is there any way i can do that in Deno??

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for an `address` property on a `Buffer` instance in Node.js (e.g. [Buffer | Node.js v14.18.1 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/buffer.html)). Can you link to the documentation for the property you mention and/or provide an executable example? I get `undefined` when I run `buf.address`.

Comment: Yep my bad, i will edit the question,  can take the address of the Buffer using node addon "ffi-napi"

Answer (score 0):

In Deno 1.24 you can use [`Deno.UnsafePointer.of`](https://deno.com/blog/v1.24#removed-denounsafepointer):

> ```
> const ptr: bigint = Deno.UnsafePointer.of(new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]));
> call_symbol(ptr, 3);
> ```

Depending on your use case you might not need the actual address. Deno 1.15 added some [FFI improvements](https://deno.com/blog/v1.15#ffi-improvements) including support for buffer arguments in `Deno.dlopen`:

> Example:
>
> ```rust
> // print_buffer.rs
> #[no_mangle]
> pub extern "C" fn print_buffer(ptr: *const u8, len: usize) {
>   let buf = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len) };
>   println!("{:?}", buf);
> }
> ```
>
> Calling it from Deno:
>
> ```typescript
> // print_buffer.ts
> const library = Deno.dlopen("./print_buffer.so", {
>   print_buffer: {
>     parameters: ["buffer", "usize"],
>     result: "void",
>   },
> });
>
> const buffer = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
> dylib.symbols.print_buffer(buffer, buffer.length);
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> $ deno run --allow-ffi --unstable print_buffer.ts
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> ```

The same blog post mentions more support coming:

> In addition to passing buffers-as-arg, we recognize the importance of being able to use buffers-as-return-value and plan to support this feature in the coming releases.

If you really need the address for some purpose in your JS/TS code then you could create a external library API call for exposing such from the native language you are working in. If this is something that you feel should be built-in then I suggest [submitting a new issue.](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/new)

Comment: yes i will follow the solution of exposing the functionality from a dll, i was just trying to use  'ffi-napi' in deno using  CommonJS module loading or import from a CDN but no luck.  Thanks

Comment: Do you even need the actual address? If you're not going to use it for anything other than calling other code you might not need the actual address…

Comment: I managed to get the actual address by returning the buf from Rust as ref to slice, and the correct address was 16 bytes after the address returned (first 16 bytes hold  the size of slice i suppose), the funny thing is i found out the hard way Deno ffi cannot deal with 64-bit integers  so i cannot pass the address to another function using ffi ( https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11641 )...

Comment: @odium you can using bigint

Comment: @Rainb yeah support for bigints in ffi was added last year addressing the issue i was referring (https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/14523) also now can get the address of a buffer with Deno.UnsafePointer.of no need to use Rust

Comment: thank you @odium, I've updated this answer to reference such